# Unable to save data on an onClick within react.js app - codepen attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am new to `react.js` and am working on creating a small project. On this small project, I am trying to implement a sort of tagging. The tagging is actually a collection of static text that renders for each of the transactions. I have a `save tag` button which I am having trouble getting an `onClick` event to save correctly without breaking my other `onChange` event for the different transactions.

Once the a `tag` is selected and the user clicks the `Save Tag` button, the tag should then be saved to the `this.self.tags` collection where it will then render to the view.

I have made a codepen with my work in progress solution, I appreciate all the help in advance!

http://codepen.io/jaycdave/pen/ggpPzq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the  reference to the `test` method should be as a prop vs a class reference:

`function Transaction ({ amount, name, tags, test }) {}`

Transaction can then take test like this:

`<Transaction test={this.test} key={idx} amount={amount} name={name} tags={ this.state.tags} />`

Here's a working codepen -> http://codepen.io/dabit3/pen/dNoMEy?editors=0010#0